# Move 2 dimensional array lines one level lower

Tags: c#, arrays

I've got 2 dimensional array that looks sth like that:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I'd like to copy every line one level lower, with generating new first one with my method, to look like this:

```
x x x
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

The last line before copying will be deleted. Is there any better way to do this than just copying everything to new array and then copying everything back to the original one?

Comment: you don't need to waste memory for temporary array, you can do in-place move

Comment: @Lashane is correct. Try displaying a sample of what you put together so far so others on here can help debut what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the values without create a temporary array:

```
for (int j = arr.GetLength(1) - 1; j > 0 ; j--)   // replaces the values  
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)    // of each row with the  
        arr[i, j] = arr[i, j - 1];                // previous row values
```

Then, copy the new values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    arr[i, 0] = /* new row values */
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this function achieves what you want;

```
    public  int?[,] PushDown(int?[,] intArray)
    {
        for (var i = intArray.GetLength(0) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (var j = intArray.GetLength(0) - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if ((i - 1) < 0)
                {
                    intArray[i, j] = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    intArray[i, j] = intArray[i - 1, j];
                }
            }
        }
        return intArray;
    }
```